# Scanner & .hasNext() issue

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am new to Java and very new to the `Scanner` class. I am writing a program which asks the user for a word and then this word is searched for within a file. Each time the word is found, it is printed on a new line in a JOptionPane, as well as the word before and after it. Everything is functioning as it should, with two exceptions:

1. If the word being searched for happens to be the last word in the file then a "NoSuchElementException" is thrown.
2. If the word being searched for appears twice in a row (unlikely, but still a problem I discovered), it only returns it once. For example, if the word being searched for was "had" and "He said that he had had enough. He had been up all night" were sentences in the file, then the output is:

   ```
   he had had
   He had been
   ```

   whereas it should be:

   ```
   he had had
   had had enough.
   He had been
   ```

I believe that my problem lies in the fact that I use a `while(scan.hasNext())` and within this loop I use `scan.next()` twice. I cannot find a solution for this though, while still achieving what I would like the program to return.

Here is my code:

```
//WordSearch.java
/*
 * Program which asks the user to enter a filename followed
 * by a word to search for within the file. The program then
 * returns every occurrence of this word as well as the
 * previous and next word it appear with. Each of these
 * occurrences are printed on a new line when displayed
 * to the user.
 */

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class WordSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        String fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of the file to be searched:");
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileName);

        String searchWord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the word to be searched for in \"" + fileName + "\":");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(reader);

        int occurrenceNum = 0;
        ArrayList<String> occurrenceList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String word = "", previousWord, nextWord = "", message = "", occurrence, allOccurrences = "";

        while(scan.hasNext()){
            previousWord = word;
            word = scan.next();

            if(word.equalsIgnoreCase(searchWord)){
                nextWord = scan.next();

                if(previousWord.equals("")){
                    message = word + " is the first word of the file.\nHere are the occurrences of it:\n\n";
                    occurrence = word + " " + nextWord;
                }
                else{
                    occurrence = previousWord + " " + word + " " + nextWord;
                }

                occurrenceNum++;
                occurrenceList.add(occurrence);
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < occurrenceNum; i++){
            allOccurrences += occurrenceList.get(i) + "\n";
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message + allOccurrences);

        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Also, on a side note: How can I implement `scan.useDelimeter()` to ignore any, question marks, commas, periods, apostrophes etc?

Comment: Might I suggest that you break this out into multiple functions?

Comment: Yes I was planning on doing so and cleaning it all up afterwards.

Comment: .... right after we all had to read through it. Note that breaking up code into functions often helps you find issues like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If the word being searched for happens to be the last word in the file then a `NoSuchElementException` is thrown.

This is because of this line:

```
if(word.equalsIgnoreCase(searchWord)) {
    nextWord = scan.next();
    ...
}
```

You do not check if the `scan` actually `hasNext()`, going straight for `scan.next()`. You can fix this by adding a conditional with a call to `scan.hasNext()`

> If the word being searched for appears twice in a row (unlikely, but still a problem I discovered), it only returns it once.

That the same problem is in play here: when you find a word, you retrieve the next one right away.

Fixing this is a little tricky: you need to change your algorithm to look at one word at a time, and use `previousWord` (which you store anyway) for use of subsequent iterations of the `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, all is _nearly_ working well! My last problem is if the word being searched for appears, but is followed by a period/comma/question mark/etc, then it is not recognised as a match. I have seen the `Scanner.useDelimter()` method, but I really do not understand the format of it and how to get it to function correctly. Could you briefly explain this to me please?

Comment: @KOB One way to fix this is to use `replaceAll` to remove all non-word characters from both ends of your string, i.e. `nextWord = scan.next().replaceAll("^\\W+", "").replaceAll("\\W+$", "");`

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is just call hasNext before using next again.

```
while(scan.hasNext()){
    previousWord = word;
    word = scan.next();

    if(word.equalsIgnoreCase(searchWord) && scan.hasNext()){ // this line change
        nextWord = scan.next();

        if(previousWord.equals("")){
            message = word + " is the first word of the file.\nHere are the occurrences of it:\n\n";
            occurrence = word + " " + nextWord;
        }
        else {
            occurrence = previousWord + " " + word + " " + nextWord;
        }

        occurrenceNum++;
        occurrenceList.add(occurrence);
    }
}
```

You want to not use equals with ignore case. You want to just use .equals().

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to save *two* words the way you are currently saving `previousWord`. Something like:

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    previousWord = word;
    word = nextWord;
    nextWord = scan.next();
```

Then you check `word`. If it matches what you need, then you can print it together with `previousWord` and `nextWord`. That is, in every iteration, you are checking the word you read in the previous iteration.

This way you only need one `hasNext()` and one `next()` in your loop.

Note that after the end of the loop, `nextWord` might actually be your word. This would mean your word is the last word in the file, and you should check for this and print it accordingly.

Comment: would this not then sort of flip the problem and it would not recognise the word if it is this first word in the file?

Comment: No. Because although you only check it in the second round rather than the first, `previousWord` will still be `""` at that time, and you'll find it. The only problem the delayed processing causes is when the word is the last one in the file - as I already mentioned. You may also want to watch out for a case there is only one word in the file.